# Google App Script throws Unexpected token e in JSON at position 0 but only sometimes

Tags: javascript, json, google-apps-script, urlfetch

One answer for post request said to stringify the JSON payload, but I am sending a get request

```js
var list= [ "bitcoin","ethereum","litecoin","dogecoin","stellar","cardano","tezos","0x","uniswap"]
var url = "https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/simple/price?ids="+list.join(",")+"&vs_currencies=usd"
var headers={ "accept": "application/json", "muteHttpExceptions":true} 
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers));
Logger.log(response)
```

The error occurs at line 4.

I thought maybe I should stringify the headers , so I did `JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, JSON.stringify(headers)))` But it raised the exception `Bad Value` at this same line

The problem is that, the initial code is running fine for most of the times, but sometimes it raises that exception

Comment: You must somehow log the requests and check the ones that are failing, maybe the service is sporadically broken or there is some request limit.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you have the response object and not the string data..

```
var response = JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers));

//to:

var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,headers);
var data = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
```